# Rails 5: rails-jquery-autocomplete routes blocked by page routes

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete, routes

I'm using the rails-jquery-autocomplete gem (https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete) with Rails 5 to get my database searches to autocomplete. Unfortunately, The routes already in place for my Listings model seem to be interfering with the one I'm trying to get into place now.

listings_controller.rb:

```
autocomplete :listing, :community, full:true, :extra_data => [:subdivision]
```

routes.rb:

```
get '/listings/:listing_id/:address/:mls', to: 'listings#show', as: 'listing'

post 'listings/:listing_id', to: 'clients#textme', as: 'new_text_client'

resources :listings do
  get :autocomplete_listing_community, :on => :collection
end
```

passing all three routes through `resources: :listings do` gets:

```
ArgumentError: Invalid route name, already in use: 'listings' 
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or 
you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same 
naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` 
as explained here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-
routes-created
```

when I run `rake routes`. However, doing it as shown gets this:

```
ArgumentError: Invalid route name, already in use: 'listings' 
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or 
you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same 
naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` 
as explained here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created
```

How do I get these all working together?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `except` for `resources` then it will work without this like

```
get '/listings/:listing_id/:address/:mls', to: 'listings#show', as: 'listing'

resources :listings, except: [:show] do
    get :autocomplete_listing_community, :on => :collection
end
```

see this as `rake routes`

```
                            listing GET    /listings/:listing_id/:address/:mls(.:format)      listings#show
                        new_text_client POST   /listings/:listing_id(.:format)                    clients#textme
autocomplete_listing_community_listings GET    /listings/autocomplete_listing_community(.:format) listings#autocomplete_listing_community
                               listings GET    /listings(.:format)                                listings#index
                                        POST   /listings(.:format)                                listings#create
                            new_listing GET    /listings/new(.:format)                            listings#new
                           edit_listing GET    /listings/:id/edit(.:format)                       listings#edit
                                        PATCH  /listings/:id(.:format)                            listings#update
                                        PUT    /listings/:id(.:format)                            listings#update
                                        DELETE /listings/:id(.:format)                            listings#destroy
```

Comment: You can't work with as same route name twice, you need consider one, routing always unique see the doc http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created

Comment: This looks really good, but I'm still getting the naming error on running `rake routes`.

Comment: On my hand, it's working, you have seen on my answer, Right? I think somewhere misspelled, you can check carefully

Comment: I saw it and tried it, but it's not reading the restriction on mine when I try it.